# Issue with data table widget of flutter but when I remove rows data get remove but corresponding rows are still there

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

https://pub.dev/packages/data_tables

Using data_tables row is not removing while data is removed, especially in the case of pagination where I define rows per page but it cant get updated while removing the data of some rows. Has anyone face the same issue and has anyone find any feasible solution?

well I got my issue solved by replacing this

```
  itemCount: _items?.length ?? 0
```

with

```
 itemCount: _rowsPerPage ?? 0
```

because my list length is not updating and that's why rows are created but as far as I know this might be a not feasible solution, here I am updating  _rowsPerPage when state changes at the same item items length also get change but that does not make an effect on Ui

Comment: post your code, there are no oracles

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/data_tables#-example-tab-   refer this , I have used different data but same logic as shown in this  example